# Why has ThermostatEco.SetMode stopped working?

Tags: nest-device-access

Sending the [ThermostatEco.SetMode](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/thermostat-eco#setmode) command appears to succeed, but the command either never makes it to or is ignored by the thermostat.

This happens whether trying to set eco mode to either MANUAL_ECO or NONE.

The thermostat eco mode can be changed using the device, using schedules, successfully using auto-away, using the Google Home app, and using the Nest app.

This used to work and nothing has changed on my side.

Has there been a change in the API or permissions required? Why are Google's apps able to change the mode but not my own using the SDM API?

Please see this thread for further reports of failure: https://github.com/home-assistant/core/issues/90619

Google Public Issue Tracker link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/288913306

Comment: We had this issue happen due to migration around that time, but was rolled back after shortly. This issue was found to happening on certain legacy models of thermostats. Could you please confirm if you are still experiencing this issue ?

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: We run a service managing thousands of Nest thermostats and started seeing this happen across a good percentage of those thermostats roughly at the end of March. Issue has not been corrected yet.

Comment: Can you open a ticket in this regard on the public issue tracker (https://issuetracker.google.com/) ? We will route it to the concerned team so that they can take a look into this issue and provide you with a solution.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/288913306

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google have resolved the issue now. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/288913306

Comment: @starball can you tell me why the edit please? Was there something bad about my answer before? So I know how in future. Thankyou for your help

Comment: read [/help/privileges/comment](/help/privileges/comment) (I inlined an important link that was only in a comment of yours since comments are second-citizens and can be deleted at any time) and also mildly related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011/997587